# what belongs to express.js middleware layer

Tags: express, middleware

I do not know what belongs to the **middleware** layer in **express.js**. Can all the methods that are not part of the HTTP protocol methods, ( but belongs to namespace of main app ) be considered middleware?
For example **app.set,app.param...**

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware layer is a list of functions express will execute to process incoming requests. It is defined by your calls to `app.use`.

`app.set`, `app.param`, etc have nothing to do with the middleware stack directly and are thus unrelated.

The one bit of deep magic is that express has a piece of middleware called the router which it normally adds to the middleware chain automatically the first time you call any of the HTTP method "verb" methods: `app.(get|post|put|head|del|patch|etc)`, express will see if the router has been added to the middleware stack and insert it if needed.